# Excel vba to sent Outlook mail: .Send function does not function

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have the following code written (see attachments). I have no problem in the .Display function - here the three test mails show up. But with the .Send function it bugs.

[image]

Please help.

Br.
Esben

Comment: What error exactly do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Outlook object model may trigger a security issue/guard when Outlook is automated from an external application. See ["A program is trying to send an e-mail message on your behalf" warning in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/security/a-program-is-trying-to-send-an-email-message-on-your-behalf) for more information.